# converting 3 column dataframe to matrix with columns defined by range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a 3 column dataframe. Let's say my columns are *"doc"*, *"word"*, *"count"* and each row shows number of occurrences of a word in a document.

```
| doc | word | count |
+-----+------+-------+
|   0 |    0 |    10 |
|   0 |    7 |     2 |
|   0 |    4 |     5 |
|   1 |    2 |     5 |
+-----+------+-------+
```

I want to convert this dataframe to a matrix having rows as documents and columns as words so I do the following:

```
matrix = pd.pivot_table(my_df, index="doc", columns="word", values="count", fill_value=0)
```

What I get is a matrix having columns `[0,2,4,7]`. However, what I want is to have another range for my columns, e.g. `range(10): [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. This latter will end up some columns having all entries as 0 and this is what I want.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: please give a input/output example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to create a sparse matrix document vs words, you could do:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

rows, cols, data = zip(*df.to_numpy())
mat = csr_matrix((data, (rows, cols)), shape=(max(rows) + 1, max(cols) + 1))
res = pd.DataFrame(data=mat.toarray())
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0  10  0  0  0  5  0  0  2
1   0  0  5  0  0  0  0  0
```

With this approach the *range* is determined automatically.

**UPDATE**

If you want to have 10 columns you could do:

```
rows, cols, data = zip(*df.to_numpy())
mat = csr_matrix((data, (rows, cols)), shape=(max(rows) + 1, 10))
res = pd.DataFrame(data=mat.toarray())
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  10  0  0  0  5  0  0  2  0  0
1   0  0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Great answer! thanks! However, I want my own range of columns which I can simply give in the shape.

Comment: @HooriM. I don't understand your request, what do you mean by a range, what happens if a document number is outside that range?

Comment: That does not happen. I know how many columns exist (like number of distinct words of a language in a static "doc", "word" dataset) and whatever index I have will fall within my range.

Comment: @HooriM. The code will adapt to the number of distinct words and docs there are. That is what this part does `shape=(max(rows) + 1, max(cols) + 1)`

Comment: Yeah, this is perfect. For my purpose, as I want to have columns in `range(10)` I can put it as `shape = (max(rows) + 1, 10)`

Comment: @HooriM. Yes, you can. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for `reindex`:

```
matrix = (pd.pivot_table(df, index="doc",
                        columns="word", 
                        values="count", fill_value=0)
            .reindex(range(10), axis=1, fill_value=0)
         )
```

Output:

```
word   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
doc                                
0     10  0  0  0  5  0  0  2  0  0
1      0  0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want! However, for performance, are there two rounds of iteration of the matrix? One for construction of matrix with existing values in "word" column and another round for adding non-existing columns to the matrix?

Comment: Yes, but the overhead would be minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the columns that do not exist and fill with 0:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(my_df, index="doc", columns="word", values="count", fill_value=0)
for c in range(10):
    if c not in df.columns:
        df[c] = 0
matrix = df[list(range(10))].values
```